# Rails : slideUp() is working but with no transition

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, slideup

For a simple to-do-list project I would like to use a .slideUp() method to delete a task. This work fine as the line disappear, but the action is baldly executed, with no smooth transition effect. If I change the duration of the .slideUp() method, the action is executed sooner or later, but still with no transition effect.

Do I need to require a particular file or gem ? 
Does the .slideUp() method work on every html tag ? (here it is a table, not a ul)

Thanks for your help!

**Update**
I extended the "tr" height to 90px and observed that the slideUp() works perfectly until the animation meet the text inside "tr" and "td" tags. At this moment, the animation "stops" and few ms later the line finally disappear. It is as if the animation would work correctly on white spaces of the line and bug on text.

// my TaskController and the destroy action

```
def destroy
 @task = Task.find(params[:id])
 @task.delete

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  format.js { }
 end
end
```

// the destroy.js.erb

```
$('tr[data-task-id="<%= @task.id %>"]').slideUp(500);
```

// index.html.erb file (index is root_path) (extract)

```
<% @tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
 <tr data-task-id="<%= task.id %>">
  <td class="text-center"><%= index + 1 %></td>
  <td><%= task.title %></td>
  <td class="text-center"><%= task.time.to_s + " h"%></td>
  <td class="text-center">
  <%= link_to task, method: :delete, remote: true do %>
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Update : 
It replaced the <tr> and <td> tags with <ul> and <li> ones and now it works !! Maybe .slideUp() do not work correctly with every html tags or there are some differences between default parameters in table vs list.

Answer (score 0):

You may need  to add the easing :

```
$("tr[data-task-id="<%= @task.id %>"]").slideUp({ duration: 500, easing: "easeInOutQuart" });
```

Comment: Thank you Othmane. Unfortunately, the issue persists. I'll check if any requirements are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out why the slideUp() effect is not entirely smooth with tr tags, but I solved it (not perfect but okay for the moment) by animating both td tags and tr tags with a small delay between them :

```
$("td[data-task-id=<%= @task.id %>]").slideUp(240);
$("tr[data-task-id=<%= @task.id %>]").slideUp(500);
```